# How to get an EmberJs checkbox to send an action with multiple parameters

Tags: ember.js

How do you get a checkbox using the `{{input}}` helper in EmberJs to send an action with multiple parameters?

Here is the current template:

```
<input
  type="checkbox" 
  class="t-dtd-field-checkbox" 
  checked="checked" 
  {{action "updateRequest" option field ticket}}
>
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
{{input
  type="checkbox" 
  class="t-dtd-field-checkbox" 
  checked={{option.checked}} 
  {{action "updateRequest" option field ticket}}
}}
```

However, this is causing a syntax error, and not sure how to get the syntax correct?

Also, how do you get the checkbox's value to update in the DOM on keypress?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation here (under actions):
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/templates/input-helpers/

You will find your answer here:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/tutorial/autocomplete-component/

```
{{input
  type="checkbox" 
  class="t-dtd-field-checkbox" 
  checked=option.checked 
  on-click=(action "updateRequest" option field ticket)
}}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I believe `onchange={{action (action "updateRequest" option field ticket)}}` with a native input is the better alternative, if you still want to receive the event as a parameter, which will be the last one.